# Contour Label Problem

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Consider:

```
f[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2;
g[x_, y_] = x^4 + y^4;
critPts = 
 Solve[{Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] == \[Lambda] Grad[g[x, y], {x, y}], 
   g[x, y] == 1}, {x, y, \[Lambda]} \[Element] Reals]
```

Then:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, g[x, y]],
 Mesh -> {{1}},
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Yellow},
 Epilog -> {
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. critPts
   }]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

Now, we add specific contours.

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 Contours -> {1, Sqrt[2]},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, g[x, y]],
 Mesh -> {{1}},
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Yellow},
 Epilog -> {
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. critPts
   }]
```

Which produces this image.

[image]

Now, if you hover your mouse over the two contours, tooltip labels of 1 and $\sqrt2$ appear.

Now consider this:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 Contours -> {1, Sqrt[2], 3},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, g[x, y]],
 Mesh -> {{1}},
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Yellow},
 Epilog -> {
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. critPts
   }]
```

Which produces this image.

[image]

Now, hover your mouse over each contour and you will see the incorrect tooltip labels pop up.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Wow. Almost certainly? For simplicity, compare `ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {1, Sqrt[2], 3}]` to `ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {1, N@Sqrt[2], 3}]`.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm concerned, this is a clear bug.

Let's do a small amount of spelunking:

```
p1 = ContourPlot[f[x, y]
  , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}
  , Contours -> {1, N@Sqrt[2], 3}, ContourShading -> None];
p2 = ContourPlot[f[x, y]
  , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}
  , Contours -> {1, Sqrt[2], 3}, ContourShading -> None];
GraphicsRow@{p1,p2}
```

Hovering on the outer-most contour yields:

[image]

[image]

To be sure that these contours are mislabeled, let's extract the contours and plot them with the values of the `Tooltip`s:

```
ListLinePlot[#1, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, #2}}] & @@@ Cases[Normal@p1, Tooltip[{__, Line[a_]}, b_] :> {a, b}, Infinity]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[#1, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, #2}}] & @@@ Cases[Normal@p2, Tooltip[{__, Line[a_]}, b_] :> {a, b}, Infinity]
```

[image]

The contours are absolutely mislabeled when you use the symbolic `Sqrt[2]` instead of the approximate value `N@Sqrt[2]`.

---

As noticed by `J.M.`, the problem is that `ContourPlot` sorts the values of the contour, and of course,

```
Sort[{1, Sqrt[2], 3}]
```

yields

```
(* {1, 3, Sqrt[2]} *)
```

We can see this by evaluating

```
TracePrint[ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {1,Sqrt[2], 3}, ContourShading -> None], SortBy[__], TraceInternal -> True]
```

Comment: Spelunking (that is, `TracePrint[ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {1, Sqrt[2], 3}, ContourShading -> None], SortBy[__], TraceInternal -> True]`) shows that this is indeed due to mis-sorting; cf. `Sort[{1, Sqrt[2], 3}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Ah, of course it is! Moral of the story: use approximate values for the numbers so that the sorting works correctly. I wonder if this is a "Possible Issue" somewhere in the documentation. In that sense, it might not actually be a bug.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be, but I will still classify this as a bug.